How to find data about light servers
I'm doing some research around light clients and light servers and need to find answers to these questions:

How many light clients can a full node reasonably serve without impacting performance
What % of full nodes are currently serving light clients?

For the first question i know the answer depends on the computational power of the full node and the percentage time it allots to run a light server.
But how do I find the exact computational power to serve one light client?
